# The foot page doesn't occupy all the width of the page, what should I use to occupy all the width?

Tags: html, css

The table that I have inserted doesn't occupy all the width of the page, I mean there is a space between the bottom and the foot, and a space between the left border and the foot.

Here is my code:

```
<footer style="background-color:#444; width:100%; height:200px; border-bottom:0px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</footer>
```

Comment: By the space between the left border and the foot, do you mean the margin of the body? If so, set `body {margin:0}`. If not, please elaborate.

Comment: Its working thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean but if you mean the table isn't filling the size of your footer then you'll need to set it to `width:100%` and `height:100%` because by default a table is only as big as it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

try to add a position :

```
position : absolute;
bottom:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css rule:

```
footer > table {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I added *red border* around table just to illustrate that table gets the wanted dimensions.

Notice that percentages are relative to parent element's width and height, and as advice try to separate html and css.

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zjd6kneb/)